# how to make code valid without && operator?

Tags: javascript

How can i make this code valid without && operator if there's a way please let me know..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var a=prompt("Enter username");
    var b=prompt("Enter password");


    if(a=="admin" && b=="hello") /// make this valid without && logical operator /// but only in this single line in (If Block)
    {
        alert("Welcome");
    }

    else
    {
        alert("Invalid");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Put `if (b == 'hello') ...` inside the first `if` block.

Comment: what's wrong with && ??

Comment: nothing wrong with && operator but it is task assigned by teacher....

Comment: bruh, tell ur teacher to quit his job. His poisoning future devs.

Comment: @Teemu that does not work. `false === false` is true.

Comment: @niry Indeed, I should wake up before commenting ...

Answer (score 5):

```
 var a=prompt("Enter username");
 var b=prompt("Enter password");


if ([a,b].toString() == ['admin','hello'].toString()) {

  alert("Welcome");

} else{

  alert("Invalid");

}
```

Comment: thank you so much ma'am its working but is it possible we can make this with not equal operator.. ?

Comment: you can try this :

var a=prompt("Enter username");
 var b=prompt("Enter password");


if ([a,b].toString() != ['admin','hello'].toString()) {

  alert("Invalid");

} else{
 alert("Welcome");
 

}

Answer (score 4):

One must wonder why would you want such thing, however, it is possible:

```js
var a=prompt("Enter username");
var b=prompt("Enter password");

var valid = false;

if(a=="admin")
{
  if(b=="hello")
  {
    alert("Welcome");
    valid = true;
  }
}

if (!valid)
{
    alert("Invalid");
}
```

Here is another option, just for you:

```js
var a=prompt("Enter username");
var b=prompt("Enter password");

if ((a=="admin") * (b=="hello"))
{
    alert("Welcome");
}
else 
{
    alert("Invalid");
}
```

And one more:

```js
var a=prompt("Enter username");
var b=prompt("Enter password");

if ((a!="admin") || (b!="hello"))
{
    alert("Invalid");
}
else 
{
    alert("Welcome");
}
```

And last one for today:

```js
var a=prompt("Enter username");
var b=prompt("Enter password");

if (((a=="admin") + (b=="hello")) === 2)
{
    alert("Welcome");
}
else 
{
    alert("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Didn't downvote but you could do with some explanation instead of just throwing up a stack of code. For example, it's not immediately obvious where you have move "Welcome"  from the `if` to the `else`, i.e. inverted the logic.

Comment: I'll be happy to explain each way! yes. On the reverse example, logically both should match (yes AND yes) so in order not to use AND (&&) you could just ask (no OR no) - does one of them not match? that is the reverse of (yes AND yes)

Comment: @JonP, the arithmetic ones, because of the signs (+, *) - true is being translated into 1 and false into zero. The object one is simply testing if the keys exists in a nest way, the `||{}` provides an empty object to test in case none found.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var a=prompt("Enter username");
var b=prompt("Enter password");


if(a=="admin")
{
    if (b=="hello")
        alert("Welcome");
    else
        alert("Invalid");
}
else
{
    alert("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: thank vicker313 but i have been given a task that i have to use only logical operator in If Line (-----------)

Comment: @jahangirshah Can you show us what is the full task given to you?

Comment: @jahangirshah What is going on?  `&&` is a logical operator you already have, and you're specifically asking for the code without `&&`...

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  var a=prompt("Enter username");
  var b=prompt("Enter password");


  if(a=="admin" && b=="hello") /// make this valid with logical operator ///
  {
   alert("Welcome");
  }

  else
  {
   alert("Invalid");
  }

 </script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you edit the question to include that? It's difficult to read in that comment.

Answer (score 0):

it would be funny, or maybe like this

```
var a=prompt("Enter username");
var b=prompt("Enter password");


if (a!='admin'||b!='hello')
{
    alert("Invalid");
}
else
{
    alert("Welcome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life miserable, you can do this:

```js
var a = 'hello';
var b = 'world';

if ([a,b].toString() == ['hello','world'].toString()) 
  console.log('match');
else
  console.log('no match');
```